# 2022 Graduation Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

**UPDATE**: After discussing it with the moderation team, the Community Management Team went ahead and [scheduled an election to start on October 31](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/743/4959).

---

Math Educators Stack Exchange graduated from beta late last year. After discussing with the current moderators and the community management team, a graduation election for the moderation team could happen as soon as October of 2022. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, we're posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position. As mentioned, we're hoping the nomination period would start some time in October '22.

Since post-beta elections need to be competitive, the interest check will help us determine how many slots we should have. To run a three slot election, we would need at least four candidates.

The winners of the graduation election will make up the new moderation team. As then community manager Jon Ericson wrote in 2018:

> On graduation, all moderators must stand for re-election if they wish
> to continue in the role. There will be no difference between
> moderators who ran for an election during beta and moderators we
> appoint.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.

Comment: To add context: I do not plan to run in this election.

Comment: May I ask why you do not wish to run in this election, @Chris? Also, thank you for giving your time to the site. :)

Comment: I love this site, but it would be best for someone else to take over; I'm having many more negative interactions than positive ones and I am confident someone else with a different outlook could have many more positive experiences.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that... Hopefully your experience will change for the better once you've handed in your diamond.

Answer (score 7):

I hope to continue as a moderator. (I will post more for the nomination process later.)